# If $T$ and $T^2$ have same image, then $N(T) \cap Im(T)={0}$

Tags: linear-algebra

Let V be a finite dimensional vectorial space and $T:V \rightarrow V$ a linear operator. Show that if  $T$ and $T^2$ have same image, then $N(T) \cap Im(T)={0}$.

My first attempt to solve this problem was think in the matrix associated to the linear transformation. I tried to use the fact that the span of the column vectors of the matrix T was equal to the span of vectors of the matrix T^2, but as I don't know the dimension of the matrix T, this problem got very complex.

Comment: Quite concretely: What would happen if there were a nonzero vector  $v$ in the intersection? Of course, such a $v$ will be of the form $Tx$ for some $x\in V$. What happens next?

Answer (score 2):

Consider the endomorphism $T$ restricted to its image. This gives an endomorphism $T'$ of $T(V)$. The assumption that $T^2$ and $T$ have the same image implies that $T'$ is surjective. Hence, since $T(V)$ is finite-dimensional, $T'$ is also injective. This implies that $\mathrm{Ker} \ T \cap T(V)=0$.

Comment: I'm not used to the concept of endomorphism, so why $T^2 \ and \ T$ having the same image implies T' being surjective and why the dimension of T(V) being finite implies T' being injective?

Answer (score -1):

The proof is indeed rather sketchy: If $w$ belongs to $N(T) \cap \mbox{Im} T$, then $w=T(v)=0$, for some $v$ in $V$. Using the hypothesis $\mbox{Im} T=\mbox{Im} T^2$, we get
the sequence of identities 
$$w=T(w)=T(0)=0$$
so that $w\in \{0\},$ as desired.

Comment: You started off assuming $w=0,$ which is what you need to prove.  Also note that whatever method you use to prove this _must_ use the fact $V$ is finite dimensional (there are counterexamples in infinite-dimensional vector spaces)

Comment: Sure, @BrianMoehring! You are right. The right argument would be $T(w)=0$ instead of $w=T(v)=0$. In any case, by assuming that $V$ is finite dimensional, one can make use of the auxiliar mapping $U: \mbox{Im T}  \right \mbox{Im T^2}$ to show that under the hypothesis $\mbox{Im} T=\mbox{Im} T^2$ one has the sequence of identities
$$\dim (N(T)\cap \mbox{Im} T)=dim (N(U)\cap \mbox{Im} T)=dim \mbox{Im} T-dim \mbox{Im} T^2=0.$$

Thus $N(T)\cap \mbox{Im} T=\{0\}$ ($\{0\}$ is the only subspace with dimension zero (0)).